# How to apply color to a specific a tag?

Tags: html, css

I've the following structure:

```
<li class="dsq-widget-item">     
    <a href="https://disqus.com/by/"><img class="dsq-widget-avatar" src="#"></a>
    <a class="dsq-widget-user" href="https://disqus.com/by//">Foo</a>    
    <span class="dsq-widget-comment">
         <p>Hello</p>
    </span>  
    <p class="dsq-widget-meta">
        <a href="#">How to</a>&nbsp;·&nbsp;<a href="#">19 minutes ago</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

how you can see I've three `a` tag, I need to apply a custom color (like blue for example) only to the second `a` tag.

Actually all the links have this class:

```
.widget a {
color: #777;
}
```

any solution

Comment: *"Actually all the links are this class `.widget a`"*  - cannot see that in your HTML, you?

Comment: you have 4 `a` tags

Comment: sorry bad typo, fixed

Comment: How about `.dsq-widget-user`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan are in the css

Comment: @ilmincione in the CSS you can have `.foobar` but I cannot see it in HTML, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.dsq-widget-item a:nth-child(2) {
    color: #777;
}
```

or if you are sure:

```
.dsq-widget-user {color: #777;}
```

Comment: that is because second a tag needs to be targeted. just .dsq-widget-user {color: #777;} can be used if it is for one a tag only.

Comment: I read "I need to apply a custom color (like blue for example) only to the second a tag" as just styling the second `a` - not every 2nd `a` in the parent.

Comment: the item that I need to color is available in dsq-widget-meta

Comment: any second a tag can be styled like this, for e.g. for dsq-widget-meta: .dsq-widget-meta a:nth-child(2) {
    color: #777;
}     i think the asker got the point

Answer (score 1):

I've Just put this code in stylesheet and you'll get the desired output

```
.dsq-widget-item > a:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}
```

here I have used **Child Selector**, you can refer more from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

**Working Code:**

```css
.dsq-widget-item > a:nth-child(2){
   background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<li class="dsq-widget-item">     
    <a href="https://disqus.com/by/"><img class="dsq-widget-avatar" src="#"></a>
    <a class="dsq-widget-user" href="https://disqus.com/by//">Foo</a>    
    <span class="dsq-widget-comment">
         <p>Hello</p>
    </span>  
    <p class="dsq-widget-meta">
        <a href="#">How to</a>&nbsp;·&nbsp;<a href="#">19 minutes ago</a>
    </p>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second link has a class, so just use that to target it.

```css
a {
color: #777;
}

.dsq-widget-user {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="dsq-widget-item">     
    <a href="https://disqus.com/by/"><img class="dsq-widget-avatar" src="#"></a>
    <a class="dsq-widget-user" href="https://disqus.com/by//">Foo</a>    
    <span class="dsq-widget-comment">
         <p>Hello</p>
    </span>  
    <p class="dsq-widget-meta">
        <a href="#">How to</a>&nbsp;·&nbsp;<a href="#">19 minutes ago</a>
    </p>
</li>
```